# Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dosn't show while debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, openfiledialog

I'm building a application on Visual Studio 2015 in C#.
I'm using Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog to get a file from machine, but while debugging the code stands still at "dlg.showDialog();" and the dialog box dosn't shown up.

```
public static void OpenDialog()
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Title = "ABC";
            dlg.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Please suggest if there is any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dosn't show while debugging?

I have tested your code in my side and I did not face the error as you described and I can open the dialog successfully. So please try these suggestions:

**1)** make sure that your project is a desktop project rather than a console project.

**2)** reference `PresentationFramework.dll` under Add Reference-->Reference-->Assemblies-->select `PresentationFramework`.

**3)** disable any third party extensions under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates** to check whether an extension caused this behavior.

**4)** then close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under solution folder, `bin`, `obj` folder, then restart your project and then test again.

Then you can set breakpoint to test whether it runs successfully.

**5)** try to create a new project to test these code and if it still does not work, please repair your VS(run the vs2015 installer program and click **Repair**).